# Xamarin Form - How To set a style for MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app, xamarin.uwp

I'm developing the DMS windows UWP application In which I want to show a user information on `DataGrid`. For this I am using `MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid`. I want to change **the header size and give the border for header**. I also want to **change the list items font size**. so any one have a full style for `DataGrid`. how to hide the `DataGrid` column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the header size and give the border for header.

The header is object type that mean you could custom it's content. If you want to add border you could refer the following code. But MyToolkit does not support modify the header size.

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Width="200"
    Binding="{Binding Lastname}"
    IsAscendingDefault="False"
    >
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Padding="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="5">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="Lastname" />
        </Border>

    </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```

> change the list items font size

If you just want to change the list items font size, you could edit `DataGridTextColumn` FontSize property.

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Width="200"
    Binding="{Binding Firstname}"
    FontSize="25"
    Header="Firstname"
    />
```

> how to hide the DataGrid column ?

Just set with property as 0.

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Width="0"
    Binding="{Binding Firstname}"
    FontSize="25"
    Header="Firstname"             
    />
```

Comment: Give `DataGridTextColumn` x:Name. change it in the code behind    `TestColumn.Width = new GridLength(0);`

Comment: thank you do you have any idea about horizontal datagrid ? i want to display columns horizontally.

Comment: MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid does not provide  `ItemsPanel` just like uwp listview. So you could not make horizontal datagrid.

Comment: would you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56935712/11362349 :(

Comment: is it possible to make this Data grid responsive ?

Comment: If you have bind the data source with two way model, it will be responsive.

Comment: means in code behind i have to define the widh and height for a columns and for gatagrid ?

Comment: If  you want to make ui-responsive, you could set `VisualStateManager` in xaml just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161553/xamarin-form-how-to-make-ui-responsive-in-uwp) reply

Comment: ok now i can do this using visualstatemanager so i just need to define the column length for specific window size am i right ?

Comment: ok thank you :) can this data grid control column user can change at run time using mouse ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197324/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-ketan).

Comment: it does not support to resize with mouse