# Xamarin Form - How To checked the checkbox on another check box checked in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

My application displays the fetures permissions on `DataGrid` from database. For realizing this I am using the `MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid`. Now i want output for if user checked the admin or update/delete/create check box then View and list check box checked vice versa same for the and also i want to set checkbox checked value from database. 
thanks in advance.

**Image**

[image]

if user checked the create/update/delete then same row list and view should be checkbox checked

[image]

if user checked the view check box then selected row column list should be checked

[image]

**Datagrid xaml**

```
  <Toolkit:DataGrid.Columns  >
            <!--Feature Column-->
            <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn CanSort="False"  >
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="#000000" Width="280" Text="Feature" />
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="14" Padding="6 0 0 0" Foreground="#333333"   Width="280" Text="{Binding featureName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <!--Create-->
            <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn Width="180" CanSort="False"  >
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Padding="0" Foreground="#000000" Text="    Create" />
                    </Border>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox Margin="30,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"  x:Name="CBCreate" DataContext="create" Tag ="{Binding featureId}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Checked="CBCreate_Checked" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <!--Update-->
            <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="180" CanSort="False"  >
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="#000000" Text="    Update" />
                    </Border>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox Margin="30 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" IsChecked="{Binding Update}"  x:Name="CBUpdate" DataContext="update" Tag ="{Binding featureId}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <!--Delete-->
            <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="180" CanSort="False"  >
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="#000000" Text="    Delete" />
                    </Border>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox Margin="30,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" IsChecked="{Binding Delete}"  x:Name="CBDelete" DataContext="delete"  Tag ="{Binding featureId}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <!--View-->
            <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="180" CanSort="False"  >
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="#000000" Text="    View" />
                    </Border>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox Checked="CBView_Checked" Unchecked="CBView_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding View}" Indeterminate="CBView_Indeterminate" Margin="30,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" x:Name="view" DataContext="{Binding featureName}" Tag ="view" AccessKey="{Binding index}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <!--List-->
            <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="180"  CanSort="False" x:Name="CLMList" >
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="#000000" Text="    List" />
                    </Border>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox x:FieldModifier="public" IsChecked="{Binding List}" Margin="30,0,0,0"  Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" x:Name="CBList" DataContext="list" Tag ="{Binding featureId}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Unchecked="CBList_Unchecked" Checked="CBList_Checked" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>
        </Toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </Toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I suppose that  the bind value of  `IsChecked` is not correct. Could share a mini sample for me with github. I will edit base on your demo.

Comment: yes i am trying to bind the true false value from code behind :( ok i will upload Datagrid code.

Comment: github link := https://github.com/patilketan888/Scan-Image-in-UWP.git download the DataGrid Checkbox demo

Comment: I tested your code, But I  have not found the issue  *if user checked the admin read check box then update and delete check box checked automatically*.

Comment: sorry :( actually i want this output

Comment: on admin row read column check box is checked then admin row update and delete column should be checked too or vice versa.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I will post code.

Comment: ok :) in simple way if user click on  update/create/delete check boxes then list and view check box row should be checked **AND** if user checked the view checkbox then List checkbox  should be checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196179/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-ketan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in simple way if user click on update/create/delete check boxes then list and view check box row should be checked AND if user checked the view checkbox then List checkbox should be checked.

For your requirement, you could use two way bind to realize. For details code please refer the following. The following code was modified base on your provided demo, you could copy and replace directly.

**FeatureData class**

```
public class FeatureData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int featureId { get; set; }
    public string featureName { get; set; }

    private bool _create;

    public bool Create
    {
        get { return _create; }
        set
        {
            _create = value;
            UpdateViewAndList(value);
            OnChanged();
        }
    }
    private bool _update;

    public bool Update
    {
        get { return _update; }
        set
        {
            _update = value;
            UpdateViewAndList(value);
            OnChanged();
        }
    }
    private bool _delete;

    public bool Delete
    {
        get { return _delete; }
        set
        {
            _delete = value;
            UpdateViewAndList(value);
            OnChanged();
        }
    }
    private bool _list;
    public bool List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
            OnChanged();
        }
    }
    private bool _view;
    public bool View
    {
        get { return _view; }
        set
        {
            _view = value;
            this.List = value;
            OnChanged();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateViewAndList(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            this.View = true;
            this.List = true;

        }
        else
        {
            this.View = false;
            this.List = false;
        }
    }
    //public string index { get; set; }
    public FeatureData(bool Create, bool Update, bool Delete, bool List, bool View, int featureId, string featureName)
    {
        this.featureId = featureId;
        this.featureName = featureName;
        this.Create = Create;
        this.Update = Update;
        this.Delete = Delete;
        this.List = List;
        this.View = View;
        //this.index = index;
    }

    private bool _IsSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected { get { return _IsSelected; } set { _IsSelected = value; OnChanged("IsSelected"); } }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**Xaml bind**

```
<Toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    <!--  Feature Column  -->
    <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn CanSort="False">
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock
                Width="280"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="#000000"
                Text="Feature"
                />
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Width="280"
                    Padding="6,0,0,0"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Foreground="#333333"
                    Text="{Binding featureName}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
    </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

    <!--  Create  -->
    <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn Width="180" CanSort="False">
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="15,0,0,0"
                    Padding="0"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="#000000"
                    Text="Create"
                    />
            </Border>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox
                    x:Name="CBCreate"
                    Margin="30,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Create,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
    </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

    <!--  Update  -->
    <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn Width="180" CanSort="False">
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="#000000"
                    Text="    Update"
                    />
            </Border>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox
                    x:Name="CBUpdate"
                    Margin="30,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Update, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
    </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

    <!--  Delete  -->
    <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn Width="180" CanSort="False">
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="#000000"
                    Text="    Delete"
                    />
            </Border>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox
                    x:Name="CBDelete"
                    Margin="30,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Delete, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
    </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

    <!--  View  -->
    <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn Width="180" CanSort="False">
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="#000000"
                    Text="    View"
                    />
            </Border>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox
                    x:Name="view"
                    Margin="30,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    IsChecked="{Binding View, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Tag="view"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
    </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

    <!--  List  -->
    <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn
        x:Name="CLMList"
        Width="180"
        CanSort="False"
        >
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="#000000"
                    Text="    List"
                    />
            </Border>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
        <Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox
                    x:Name="CBList"
                    Margin="30,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    IsChecked="{Binding List, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
    </Toolkit:DataGridTemplatedColumn>
</Toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: i am not getting [CallerMemberName] ??

Comment: Add `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` namespace.

Comment: i have so many questions in uwp would please share some link for study. i am suffering from the responsive ui issue. please give me some tricks how to do that.

Comment: For basic uwp tutorial you could following this [blog](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-001-Series-Introduction).

Comment: And if  you have any question please feel free post on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your support :) have a great day.

Comment: would you please answer my question - stackoverflow.com/q/57161553/11362349

Comment: I replied your case, hope that is helpful.